# What happens when you select a country in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am a bit confused about the meaning of country/region when creating a new tenant.
This is not the region I am used to from other services (like West US, West Europe, ...).

So: what exactly is the meaning when I select 'Germany' here? What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the country you choose, Azure AD B2C selects the closest data center/region that will hold your Azure AD B2C directory. Currently, Azure AD B2C only uses the European and North American regions. If you select Germany, your Azure AD B2C directory will be created in a data center in the European region.